# sending email after specific date

Tags: laravel, email

i am using laravel 5.2
i want to prepare an email to be sent after 50 days when the user click on a button then go to controller
i found "later" method but i did not work, its sends the email immediately.
also i found  "scheduler" but i could not understand how to work with it because its about every day , monthly, yearly,...
what i want is after specific date only

here i try to send email after 5 minutes but it send it immediately

```
Mail::later(300,'email.final_reminder',['datastd'=>$datastd],function($mail) use ($datastd){
$mail->to($datastd['email'],$datastd['sfname'],$datastd['smname'],$datastd['slname'])->from('everyone@gmail.com')->subject('Final Report');
        });
```

Comment: You need to use a queue for this, check [Laravel Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues).

Answer (score 1):

1) Due to the long delay i would recommend an database entry with an timestamp to store the information

2) And than you can set up a queue https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues which checks every day, minute etc. for the timestamp being older than 50 days (carbon subdays and now methode), than it can send the email and delete the record